# What am I doing wrong in Minimum Subset problem?

Tags: java, dynamic-programming

The code for geeksforgeeks.

```java
class Solution {

    public int minDiffernce(int arr[], int n) { 
    
        // Your code goes here
        int range = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            range += arr[i];
        }
        boolean[][] dp = new boolean[n+1][range+1];
        for (int i = 0; i <= n + 1; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < range + 1; j++) {
                if (i == 0) dp[i][j] = false;
                if (j == 0) dp[i][j] = true;
            }
        }
        
        for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
            for (int j = 1; j <= range; j++) {
                if (arr[i] <= j){
                    dp[i][j] = dp[i-1][j-arr[i]] || dp[i-1][j];
                }
                else dp[i][j] = dp[i-1][j];
            }
        }
        ArrayList<boolean> v = new ArrayList<boolean>();
        
        for (int i = 0;i < range + 1; i++) {
            if (dp[n][i] == true) v.add(dp[n][i]);
        }
        
        int mini = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        for (int i = 0; i < range / 2; i++){
            mini = Math.min(mini, range - 2 * v[i]);
        }

        return mini;
    } 
}
```

It is throwing the following errors:

```
prog.java:53: error: unexpected type
        ArrayList<boolean> v = new ArrayList<boolean>();
                  ^
  required: reference
  found:    boolean
prog.java:53: error: unexpected type
        ArrayList<boolean> v = new ArrayList<boolean>();
                                             ^
  required: reference
  found:    boolean
prog.java:61: error: array required, but ArrayList<<any>> found
            mini = Math.min(mini, range-2*v[i]);
                                           ^
```

Comment: The line should read `ArrayList<Boolean> v = new ArrayList<Boolean>();` (note the uppercase B in Boolean. List may hold objects only, not scalar types like boolean, int and the like

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. ArrayList can only hold Objects and not primitive types. Hence, it should be -

   `ArrayList<Boolean> v = new ArrayList<Boolean>();`
2. Math.min() can have one of the four declarations mentioned below. v[i] in your code will return Boolean and result of oepration `2*v[i]` is invalid. Hence you see the error.

   `Math.min(int, int) Math.min(long, long) Math.min(float, float) Math.min(double, double)`